# Windows 8 Laptop as secondary monitor for Windows 10 Laptop

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

I have an old windows 8 touch screen Laptop that i would like to use as a second monitor for my primary windows 10 primary laptop. Just wondering if anyone knows how to do this such that:

- I don't need to upgrade to windows 10
- I don't need to pull apart the old laptop for its LCD and buy a driver etc.
- I retain the touch screen functionality of the secondary computer. (not strictly necessary)
- Connection  is wireless (again not strictly necessary but I would prefer not to clutter my desk with a hdmi cable)

I don't mind if I need to download 3rd party software either (infact I already have widi media share on the secondary computer if that helps)

Thanks
Tuna

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
https://spacedesk.net/##section1
(client/server part according to your operating systems).